# fabric js clone path-group type object

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying in fabricJs to clone a SVG object. It does ok first time but then it clones 2 times and 4 and so on. I couln't find a solution to my problem.

Here is what I tried:

```
$('#duplicate-item').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj = selectedObject;
    if (fabric.util.getKlass(obj.type).async) {
        obj.clone(function (clone) {
            clone.set({
                left: 200,
                top: 100
            });
            canvas.add(clone);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out your `selectedObject` and make sure it doesn't include any of the cloned objects. It sounds like it's duplicating the previous duplicates as well as the intended object.

Comment: Yes ... Tin Can you were right ... I called the clone function inside canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) { ... So it duplicate all my svgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a small code that loads an svg image and it adds it on the canvas. with the same way (select svg and press button) you can clone the svg object.
i hope that helps.

```
var site_url =  'http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg';

fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url, function(objects) { 
          var group = new fabric.PathGroup(objects, { 
          left: 165, 
          top: 100, 
          width: 295, 
          height: 211 
        }); 
        canvas.add(group); 
        canvas.renderAll(); 
          });
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/0fbefh52/4/

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at my exampe in jsfiddle , that is what you need.
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/0fbefh52/1/

and this is the code , you select an object and then you press the button to clone:

html:

```
<button id="duplicate-item">clone object</button>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

js:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

 var circle = new fabric.Circle({
                  radius: 20, 
                  fill: 'red', 
                  left: 100, 
                  top: 100
                });
            canvas.add(circle);

var square = new fabric.Rect({
              left: 130, 
              top: 140,
              fill: 'green',
              width: 40,
              height: 80
            });
            canvas.add(square);

canvas.renderAll();

$('#duplicate-item').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      var actObj = canvas.getActiveObject();  
        console.log('active object'+actObj);      
      var clone = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
      clone.set({left: actObj.left+10,top: actObj.top+10});
        clone.setCoords();
        canvas.add(clone); 
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
 });
```

Comment: But circle and square that you made in jsfiddle are not path-group type elements ... Can you make it with a SVG to see if it is working ?